# How can I labeled points in a list plot?

Tags: plotting

In John Robert Stinespring (2002), *Mathematica* for Microeconomics, p.76, `LabeledListPlot` is used.

But in *Mathematica* 10.3, `LabeledListPlot` is no longer available.

How can I label points in a list plot?

```
A1 = 
  LabeledListPlot[{{Subscript[x, Q], Subscript[y, CV], "A"}}, 
    DisplayFunction -> Identity]
```

> ```
> LabeledListPlot[{{10, 151.191, "A"}}, DisplayFunction -> Identity]
> ```

The whole of my code is as follows:

```
Utility(x_,y_)=x^0.4 y^0.6;
   constraint=M-Px x-Py y;
   ℒ=Utility(x,y)+λ constraint ;
   FOCs={∂ ℒ/∂x, ∂ ℒ/∂y, ∂ ℒ/∂λ};
   sols=Solve[FOCs==0,{x,y,λ}];
   {x^*,y^*,λ^*}={x,y,λ}/. Select[sols,FreeQ[#,Complex]&][[1]];
   Subscript[V, 1]=Block[{M=100,Px=1,Py=1},Utility(x^*,y^*)];

constraint0=Block[{Px=1,Py=1,M=100},constraint]
Subscript[y, 1]=y/. Solve[constraint0==0,y]
Subscript[y, 2]=y/.  Solve[Subscript[V, 1]==Utility(x,y),y]
constraintCV=Block[{Px=5,Py=1,M=Subscript[E, 2]},constraint]
Subscript[y, 3]=y/. Solve[constraintCV==0,y]

a:=200
F:=Plot[Subscript[y, 1],{x,0,a},DisplayFunction->Identity]
G:=Plot[Subscript[y, 2],{x,0,a},DisplayFunction->Identity]
H:=Plot[Subscript[y, 3],{x,0,a},PlotStyle->{Dashing[{0.01}]},DisplayFunction->Identity]
Show[F,G,H,PlotRange->{0,a},PlotLabel->"Compensating Variation",DisplayFunction->$DisplayFunction,AxesLabel->{"X","Y"}]

Subscript[V, 3]=Block[{M=100,Px=5,Py=1},Utility(x^*,y^*)]
EX=M/. Last[Solve[Subscript[V, 3]==Utility(x^*,y^*),M]]
Subscript[E, 3]=Block[{Px=1,Py=1},EX]
EV=Subscript[E, 1]-Subscript[E, 3]

constraintEV=constraint0-EV;
Subscript[y, 6]=y/. Solve[constraintEV==0,y]
Subscript[y, 7]=y/. Last[Solve[Subscript[V, 3]==Utility(x,y),y]]

H:=Plot[Subscript[y, 6],{x,0,a},PlotStyle->{Dashing[{0.01}]},DisplayFunction->Identity]
J:=Plot[Subscript[y, 7],{x,0,a},PlotStyle->{Dashing[{0.01}]},DisplayFunction->Identity]
Show[F,G,H,J,PlotRange->{0,a},PlotLabel->"Equivalent Variation",DisplayFunction->$DisplayFunction,AxesLabel->{"X","Y"}]

Subscript[x, Q]=10;
Subscript[y, CV]=y/. First[Solve[Subscript[V, 1]==Utility(Subscript[x, Q],y),y]]
Subscript[CV, Q]=Block[{Px=1,Py=1},Py Subscript[y, CV]+Px Subscript[x, Q]-Subscript[E, 1]]

Subscript[y, Q]=y/. First[Solve[Block[{x=Subscript[x, Q]},constraint0]==0,y]]
Subscript[V, Q]=Utility(Subscript[x, Q],Subscript[y, Q])
Subscript[y, EV]=y/. First[Solve[Subscript[V, Q]==Utility(Block[{M=100,Px=1},x^*],y),y]]
Subscript[EV, Q]=Block[{M=100,Py=1},Py y^*-Py Subscript[y, EV]]

Subscript[constraintCV, Q]=constraint0+Subscript[CV, Q]
Subscript[y, A]=y/. Last[Solve[Subscript[constraintCV, Q]==0,y]]
K:=Plot[Subscript[y, A],{x,0,a},PlotStyle->{Dashing[{0.01}]},DisplayFunction->Identity]
Al:=LabeledListPlot[{{Subscript[x, Q],Subscript[y, CV],"A"}},DisplayFunction-> Identity]
Show[F,G,K,A1,PlotRange->{0,a},PlotLabel->"Compensating  Variation",DisplayFunction->$DisplayFunction,AxesLabel->{"X","Y"}]
```

Comment: There is many ways how to do this. One way would be to use `Epilog` or `Tooltip`. Also I would advise you not to use subscripts in your variable or function definition unless you are highly expreienced Mathematica user. It would also be useful if you provide more information.

Comment: Thank you for your kind illustrated answer.

Answer (score 4):

**Basic example(s):**

```
data = RandomReal[1, {5, 2}];
ListPlot[Tooltip[#] & /@ data]
```

or

```
data = RandomInteger[100, {5, 2}]
ListPlot[data, Epilog -> (Text[ToString[#], #] & /@ data)]
```

**Output (Tooltip):**

[image: tooltip version]

**Output (Epilog):**

[image: epilog version]

**Reference:**

[Epilog](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html)
[Tooltip](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tooltip.html)

Comment: Thank you for your kind illustrated answer.
In this case (I added the whole process),
How can I label the point?

Comment: @userPARK the above code shows two ways how you could add labels to your plot. For more information, I would encourage you to visit the websites which I specified in **Reference** section above.

Answer (score 2):

```
data = RandomReal[1, {5, 2}];
ListPlot[data,
 Epilog -> (Text[Style[ToString[#], 12], #] & /@ data)]
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind illustrated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a few variations:

```
SeedRandom[9];
data = RandomReal[1, {5, 2}];

labels = RandomWord["Noun", Length@data]
coordlabels = ToString /@ (NumberForm[#, {3, 2}] & /@ data)

ListPlot[{data -> coordlabels}, PlotTheme -> "Scientific"]
```

[image]

---

```
ListPlot[{data -> labels}]
```

[image]

---

```
colabels = (Column[#, Alignment -> Center] & /@ 
   Transpose@{labels, coordlabels});
ListPlot[{data -> colabels}]
```

[image]

---

*or using `Callout`:*

```
ListPlot[Callout[#, NumberForm[#, {3, 2}], CalloutStyle -> Red] & /@ 
  data, PlotStyle -> Green]
```

[image]

---

These variations can also be used in conjunction with `Tooltip`.